# BF 4 render distance and interaction range

Tags: battlefield-4

As most games does, i'm sure that BF 4 has a render distance, where, past a certain point, the game does not render anything but a "generic background" (a.k.a a mountain, sky, etc...), but that does not mean that past that point there is not a legitmate interactable object (a.k.a a player, a structure, a tank, etc...).

My question here is: If i take my long ranged weapon (sniper or tank) and shoot it, can i hit a target dispite its distance? which could translate to "hey player, dispite not showing you, there was a head where your bullet landed, so, good shot!"... or the alternative is true? "hey player, your shot was supposed to hit a head, but you took it from too far away, and after X km, I stop calculating collisions for that bullet, despite the fact that physics calculations predict that it carries enough energy to kill..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Battlefield, interaction range is determined by the muzzle velocity of each particular weapon, not by render distance. Projectiles travel for 5 seconds before "disappearing" so a higher muzzle velocity results in a higher interaction range.

For example, the CS-LR4 has a muzzle velocity of 500 m/s whereas the CS5 only has a muzzle velocity of 400 m/s -- so [the CS-LR4 has a maximum distance of 2500 m whereas the CS5 is limited to a maximum distance of 2000 m](http://symthic.com/bf4-compare?CS-LR4_vs_CS5). The interaction range therefore differs from weapon to weapon. [symthic.com](http://symthic.com) has all the maximum distances.

Comment: Ah, I never caught on that it was related to muzzle velocity - I thought it was just a hard coded value for each gun.  And thanks for digging up the link for me =). I'll delete my answer.

Comment: In a way, it *is* a hard coded value for each weapon -- there's just one level of indirection with the 5 second projectile "lifetime".